# How do I make an advanced custom field a link?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom field on a product page in WooCommerce with the following code

```php
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'subtitle_link', 15);

function subtitle_link() {
    global $post;
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true);
    if(!empty($subtitle)){

        echo __("\n<br />\n<br />Enter this competition for free:", '');
        echo '<h3>'.$subtitle.'</h3>';

    }
}
```

Although this displays as it should on the front end, the URL isn't a link.

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks

Comment: `echo "<h3><a href='" . $subtitle . "'>My url</a></h3>";` - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: I don't think that will work either as I want the test from the field to link. Thanks

Comment: did you try? also check out the link I shared, this is really basic.

Comment: I have added this but it is linking everything on the page

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_subtitle_link', 15);

function my_custom_subtitle_link() {
 global $post;
 $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true);
 if(!empty($subtitle)){
  
  echo __("\n<br />\n<br />Enter this competition for free:", '');
  echo '<a href="'.$subtitle.'"</a>';
  echo "<span class='complink'>".$subtitle.'</span>';
 
  
 }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML  target Attribute

> - _blank  Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
> - _self   Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
> - _parent Opens the linked document in the parent frame
> - _top    Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
> - framename   Opens the linked document in a named frame

```php
function subtitle_link() {
    global $post;

    // Make sure this works!
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true);

    // If the above works, remove this!
    $subtitle = 'http://www.google.com';

    if( $subtitle ) {
        echo __("\n<br />\n<br />Enter this competition for free:", '');
        echo "<h3><a href='" . $subtitle . "' target='_blank'><span class='complink'>" . $subtitle . "</span></a></h3>";
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'subtitle_link', 15);
```

Comment: Yes that works and directed to Google. Its way better and I can put a static URL anyway. How would I wrap that in a span class? and make it open in a new tab? Thanks for your help